# how to hook a specific API on Windows with SetWindowsHookEx?

Tags: windows, api, hook

I am trying to hook an API (say, MessageBox()) in other processes (I may not know the process ID) on Windows, I know that I have to use the SetWindowsHookEx() function. But still, I have three  questions:

1) Can SetWindowsHookEx() function makes the hook global, i.e., not limited to current process? (When ther applications call this API, it is hooked?)

2) If I want to replace the to-be-hooked API with my own function, how should I do?

3) I read many materials, and I found the term "hook procedure" or "hook function". How should I comprehend this? Currently, I take it as the function that I will use to replace the API (say again, MessageBox).

Answer (score 3):

This is not what `SetWindowsHookEx` is for. `SetWindowsHookEx` is for hooking into windows messages, not APIs (for example if you want to know when a window changes size or gets created).

Hooking API calls is more complicated, more messy. There is no built-in way to do it; you usually want to find a library to help you such as [Detours](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/).

Comment: thanks! In fact I know something about Detours, but I want to use SetWindowsHookEx() to hook an API. Now I have some problems getting it done. Anyway, thanks for your explanation on 'SetWindowsHookEx()' and I will try Detours.

Comment: One more question, can any Detours API implement a **global** hook?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Deviare API Hook](http://www.nektra.com/products/deviare-api-hook-windows/) for this. With this library you can hook any API in 10 lines of code even with .NET
The difference with Detours is that you don't have to write the code that is inserted in each process. You can hook all the processes you want just attaching them. Then, you receive the calls in your own process.

Comment: I navigate to the website of Deviare and find it really functional. However, it seems that it does not support C/C++. I want to implement the hook with C/C++. I have download Deviare for later use. Thanks!

Comment: It does support C/C++, it's a COM object and can be used in any language.

Comment: Thanks, I went back to the Deviare forum and found that there is no C++ samples yet. It may be too long for me to start without a sample.